# Laravel stop modal attribute being updated based on user role

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm creating a system in which there are users, and user have many user roles. The user roles also contain permissions. Some fields are protected, so that they cannot be overwritten without the user possessing a specific permission.

For example, a user may have the attribute "email" which cannot be changed by the user, unless the user has the permission "update-email-address".

I originally intended to implement this concept as a trait or an abstract class, but I can't figure a way of doing this which doesn't involve either overloading the Eloquent Model constructor method, or else completely overloading another method.

What I'm hoping to do, is to be able to specify an array in a model like below, and by using a tract or extention, somehow prevent updating a model attribute:

> ```
> /**
>  * The attributes that should only be updatable by given user with the 
>  * specified permission
>  *
>  */    
> public $update_only_by_permission = [
>     'email'          => ['update-email-address'], 
> ];
> ```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You could add a middleware on the POST/PUT request then modify the request so that the key is never sent to the controller/model.

Comment: @ian In my situation there may be some attributes that can be updated, and others that cannot - based on the given user permission. I stumbled across something which led me to a solution, I've given it below,

Comment: Ah it seems I mis understood, thank you for posting your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled across a way to provide a boot method for a trait extending a model, and was able to achieve this through the following:

Trait used on many Eloquent Models:

```
use Auth;
trait AttributeVisibleByPermissionTrait {

    /**
    *   Stops updating of the object attributes if the authenticated 
    *   user does not have the given permission provided in the 
    *   $object->update_only_by_permission array.
    */
    public static function bootAttributeVisibleByPermissionTrait(){

        static::updating(function($object){ 
            foreach ($object->update_only_by_permission as $attribute => $permissions) {
                foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
                    if(!Auth::User()->can($permission)) {
                        unset($object->$attribute);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use AttributeVisibleByPermissionTrait;
    /**
     * The attributes that should only be updated by given user auth permissions
     *
     * @var array
     */    
    public $update_only_by_permission = [
        'email'              => ['update-email-address'], 
    ];
}
```